# Missing call pager in KnownContactProperties, anyone knows where is it?

Tags: windows-phone-8

You know, each contact has a call pager peroperty, but I can't find it from KnownContactProperties, do you know where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.personalinformation.knowncontactproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#properties), there is no such property.